# how to add root node tag in a XML document with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Iam parsing the xml document in SSIS through the xmlsource. It does not have any root tag. So iam trying to add the root tag to my xml document through XSLT, but getting the error as

[XML Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "There are multiple root elements. Line 11, position 2.".

what is the XSL to be used to add the root element.? Please help..this is very urgent..

Please find the xml source below

```
<organizational_unit>
  <box_id>898</box_id>
  <hierarchy_id>22</hierarchy_id>
  <parent_box_id>0</parent_box_id>
  <code>Team</code>
  <description />
  <name>CAPS Teams</name>
  <manager_title />
  <level>0</level>
</organizational_unit>
<organizational_unit>
  <box_id>967</box_id>
  <hierarchy_id>31</hierarchy_id>
  <parent_box_id>0</parent_box_id>
  <code>main</code>
  <description />
  <name>Protegent</name>
  <manager_title />
  <level>0</level>
    <organizational_unit>
       <box_id>968</box_id>
       <hierarchy_id>31</hierarchy_id>
       <parent_box_id>967</parent_box_id>
       <code>19L</code>
       <description>19L</description>
       <name>19L</name>
       <level>1</level>
    <managers>
       <manager>
          <hierarchy_mgr_id>243</hierarchy_mgr_id>
          <hierarchy_id>31</hierarchy_id>
          <box_id>968</box_id>
          <rep_id>19499</rep_id>
          <unique_rep_id>100613948</unique_rep_id>
         <first_name>Ed</first_name>
         <last_name>Kill</last_name>
      </manager>
    </managers>
    </organizational_unit>
    <organizational_unit>
        <box_id>1152</box_id>
        <hierarchy_id>31</hierarchy_id>
        <parent_box_id>967</parent_box_id>
        <code>UNKNOWN_m</code>
        <description>Unknown Reps</description>
        <name>Unknown Reps</name>
        <level>1</level>
    </organizational_unit>
</organizational_unit>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. XSL acts on XML, which in turn must be valid. If there's no root element, it's not valid, and so XSL won't talk to it. If you're got root-less XML your only option is to string-handle a root node in via something like PHP or whatever language you're using.

Comment: @Utkanos: You actually mean "well-formed" -- not "valid". An XML document is valid if: 1. It is well-formed; and 2. It satisfies a given XML Schema.

Answer (score 0):

Well which XSLT processor do you use, how do you use it? I usually don't suggest to use string processing to construct XML but if you have a fragment without a root element then perhaps doing string concatenation `"<root>" + fragment + "</root>"` is the easiest way to get a well-formed document. XSLT can work with fragments but how you do that depends on the XSLT processor or XML parser you use, for instance .NET can use an `XmlReader` with `XmlReaderSettings` with `ConformanceLevel` set to fragment, which can then be loaded in an `XPathDocument` (for processing with XSLT 1.0 and `XslCompiledTransform`) and probably also with Saxon's `XdmNode` (although I am not sure I remember that correctly).

The stylesheet would then simply do

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

to wrap all top level nodes into a `root` element.

Comment: the structure of my xml file looks like below
<organization_unit>
 <child nodes....>
</organization_unit>
<organization_unit>
 <organization_unit>
  <child nodes....>
 </organization_unit>
</organization_unit>
<organization_unit>
 <child nodes....>
</organization_unit>
once after applied you solution again i got the below error 
[XML Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "There are multiple root elements. Line 11, position 2.".   but the <root>...</root> tag is added in the xml for the first set of <organization_unit>

Comment: Your post mentions SSIS and XML source and the error message mentions XML task, I am not familiar with those tools. My suggestion for string concatenation could be done in any programming language, my suggestion to use an XmlReader in fragment mode and XSLT works if you run the transformation with .NET code (e.g. C#, VB.NET or other .NET languages). I don't know how that fits in with SSIS I am afraid, someone familiar with that needs to help tell you whether my suggestion is feasible in that context.